# React + Flux - Unload page on multi-page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

Consider a multi-page application where, when you open a page, it starts a timer responsible for fethcing data every n seconds. Now consider you want to go to another page, how would you guarantee that the timer will be stopped (as it won't be needed on the second page).

I would implement it as the following:

App.jsx

```
onClickNavigateToPageA: function() { AppActions.goToA(); }
```

AppActions.js

```
goToA: function() {
   DispatchActionToLoadComponentPageA();
   DispatchActionToStartTimer();
}
```

Now I click to go to page B. How to tell the timer to stop? If I do this (through an action, I believe) on componentWillUnmount I would be dispatching an action during an action (the action to load page B), so it is wrong.

The right way would be to register a callback (that would call an action to disable the timer) right after loading page A and then calling it when loading any other page? To my knowledge, the store should never now about the api used to fetch data from the server (including the timer, it should be on action creators).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dispatch actions with any JSON payload you want, which means you can group action types by properties of the dispatched action itself. In this case the payload from `DispatchActionToLoadComponentPageA` might be:

```
{ 
    type: 'pageLoad',
    page: 'pageA'
}
```

Which would be different from other types of actions you might dispatch like:

```
{ 
    type: 'xhrComplete',
    response: ...
}
```

Now your timer can listen for actions of type `pageLoad` and start/stop itself based on whether or not the page being loaded requires a timer.

Comment: looks like a clean solution maybe a little heavy for just a timer but clean I guess

Comment: The timer is just an example.

Comment: I understood what you are saying now. It is quite obvious, the store that started the timer when the page loaded can be responsible for stopping it when other page is required.

Comment: But consider the timer inside an api called FooApi. I don't like the idea of coupling the store with the FooApi, I would like to let it ot the action creators. Or there is no problem doing so? (I think there is, because I don't want my stores triggering actions (async).

Comment: I'm not completely following the follow up, but from what I understand about your use case, your Component will trigger an action to be dispatched when the user clicks on a button/link. The store that owns the timer will receive that action (along with your other Stores) and can look at the payload to see if it wants to act on it or not. The timer should be inside of something that is registered to listen to dispatched actions. I generally use the ActionCreator to trigger async actions and only dispatch on completion (api would not have a timer, but might rely on a Store that does).

Comment: Actually, the store does not contain any timer, the API does, as it is responsible for polling the server every N seconds, on receiving data, it triggers an action and the stores get updated. I am abstracting that from the store, as I think that nothing inside it should do anything that would trigger an action. Maybe it was not clear on my question.

Comment: I wouldnt put the timer in your API - keep that as simple as possible (no business logic like polling for page X). The timer could be as simple as a `setInterval` in your Component (on `componentDidMount`) that gets cleared on `componentWillUnmount`.

Comment: Don't you think that making the component aware of this is worse? Imagine I want to change from polling to web sockets, it would be much more coupled than agreeing that the API will provide me a live model, where, in the action creator, I would simply create an action on each update. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using your timer along with stores I wouldn't use actions and flux cycle. If it's related to stores use the flux cycle.
Anyway I would just use a common "timer" module with the needed functions and turn it on/off when needed.

Comment: Actually, when I load page A (for example), I start a timer to poll data and update my store. So, when I leave that page, I want to stop the timer (as the data update would not be needed anymore). So, you are telling me that my implementation is correct?

Comment: Where sould I be making my API calls? I am currently doing it on an action creator (one action to request, one when received/failed). Is it correct, or should the store handle thw whole process? I prefer not to couple it, that is why I prefer no to cancel the timer using a store.

Comment: doing the call in actions is perfectly fine and in my opinion the right way to proceed, actually doing it in stores would be an antipattern